# ReactiveUI Google Maps

Tags: xamarin.android, reactiveui

Question: I have a `IReactiveDerivedList<SensorViewModel>` in my ViewModel and want to subscribe to changes on it including what's already in the list before I observe it.  This then gets fed into GoogleMaps for Xamarin Android.

This seems to work when I add something :

```
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
{
    _itemsAdded = this.ViewModel.Sensors.ItemsAdded
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Select(s => new CircleOptions()
                .InvokeCenter(new LatLng(s.Latitude, s.Longitude))
                .InvokeRadius(1000)
                .InvokeFillColor(Color.Blue.ToArgb())
                .InvokeStrokeColor(Color.Red.ToArgb()))
            .Subscribe(
                Observer.Create<CircleOptions>(options => map.AddCircle(options)));
}
```

But I also need to keep track of the `Circle` returned from `map.AddCircle` so I can remove it from the map when the object goes away.  What's the reactive way to handle a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most reactive way to do it but I figured something out that seems to work:

```
    private IDisposable _itemsAdded;
    private IDisposable _itemsRemoved;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Circle> _circleMap = new Dictionary<string, Circle>();

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        _circleMap.Clear();

        _itemsAdded = this.ViewModel.Sensors.ItemsAdded
            .StartWith(this.ViewModel.Sensors)
            .Subscribe(s =>
            {
                var options = new CircleOptions()
                    .InvokeCenter(new LatLng(s.Latitude, s.Longitude))
                    .InvokeRadius(1000)
                    .InvokeFillColor(Color.Blue.ToArgb())
                    .InvokeStrokeColor(Color.Red.ToArgb());

                var circle = map.AddCircle(options);
                this._circleMap.Add(s.Id, circle);
            });

        _itemsRemoved = this.ViewModel.Sensors.ItemsRemoved
            .Subscribe(s =>
            {
                Circle circle = null;
                if (this._circleMap.TryGetValue(s.Id, out circle))
                {
                    this._circleMap.Remove(s.Id);
                    circle.Remove();
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: This looks good. You can also consider using `CompositeDisposable` to store your `IDisposable`s in one place, and replacing directly accessing `ViewModel` with `this.WhenAnyObservable()` - the latter one will save you if by some accident `ViewModel` will be null when this method is called (or when it gets replaced).

Comment: I'll switch to a `CompositeDisposable`.  The code above is in the view (Android Activity).   How would I use `WhenAnyObservable` in this case?

Comment: If you reference ReactiveUI in your Android project, this should Just Work, since `WhenAny` family are extension methods on a generic T. This stuff I mention about VM is also descibed [in the older docs](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/e2c01b8230de576e4e7a689828eebfd5193fbf67/docs/basics/whenany.md#different-kinds-of-whenanys).

Comment: I understand that, I'm just not sure how it's supposed to work with the above example.  Can you show me I would use it to improve the code above?